# Properties are not being serialized when posting as Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have this class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public CustomerOrders Orders {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class CustomerOrders : List<Order>
{
    public string CustomProperty1 {get; set;}
    public string CustomProperty2 {get; set;}
}
```

The classes are marked with `[Serializable]` and `[DataContract()]` whilst all the properties are marked with `[Datamember()]`.

When posting as Json using `HttpCLient.PostAsJsonAsync()`, the customer object is deserialized back in the controller, however both custom properties are set to null, even though they are set client-side.

Is this a problem because the `CustomerOrders` class inherits directly from `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct. The serializer will only serialize elements in the list but not extra properties of the list class. The serializer has some special handling for IEnumerable. Either make the List a property of the class or use a different Json Serializer.